# Why is the model progressively getting slower?

Tags: netlogo, patch

I have this code were one agent searches for forests to destroy them, while the other agent looks for grass that is empty meaning that there is no other agents. The code works, however every tick it gets slower. I do believe that the if´s are taxing the processor, however it should be equally taxing throught the run. I have other process in the code, but i have concluded that this one is the thats hitting hard.

Landowner Agent

Objetivo = Target patch to transform

Forest# = Property of the patches, its just what canopy it has

The world  (Map) is fairly big. Still i dont get why it gets slower over time

```
ask landowner[ifelse patch-here = objetivo  
[ifelse any? neighbors with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest1"] [set objetivo min-one-of patches with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest1"][distance myself]]
  [ifelse any? neighbors with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest2"] [set objetivo min-one-of patches with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest2"][distance myself]]
    [ifelse any? neighbors with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest3" ] [set objetivo min-one-of patches with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest3"][distance myself]]
      [ifelse any? neighbors with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest4"][set objetivo min-one-of patches with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest4"][distance myself]]
        [if any? neighbors with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest5"] [set objetivo min-one-of patches with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest5"][distance myself]]]]]]][face objetivo fd 1]]


ask expansionist [ifelse patch-here = objetivo 
[if any? neighbors with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Grass" and (not any? neighbors with [es-bosque = 1])][set objetivo min-one-of patches with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Grass" and not any? neighbors with [es-bosque = 1] and empty = 1][distance myself]]] [face objetivo fd 1]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the land cover change over time in this model? From what I see, grass is quite demanding because the distance to every single grass patch is measured, whereas forests are subdivided into categories so the distance is only measured to about 1/5 patches with forests. If the system gets progressively more grass, it should slow down. Anyway, your usage of `min-one-of` in a system with a lot of patches when you have already established that one of the neighboring patches fits the criteria is not great. You don't need to sample any other patches than the 8 neighboring ones.

Try replacing

`set objetivo min-one-of patches with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest1"][distance myself]`

with

`set objetivo one-of neighbors with [Tipo-Cobertura = "Forest1"]`

Comment: Hello, yes the land cover changes, every time any of the two agents reaches something thats not grass it turns it into grass.  I see what you say, I'm measuring twice the same thing. I ll give it a try before giving the check. Thank you for your time

Comment: Oh I didn't mean it as you measuring twice. But assuming a distribution of 50% grass, and 10% of each tree species, the first agent will sample their distance to 10% of all tiles while the second agent will sample their distance to 50% of all tiles. So 60% of all tiles get sampled. Now if the cover changes to 90% grass and 2% of each tree, the first samples 2% and the second samples 90% for a total of 92%. So changes in the percentage of grass cover of the world could explain the fact that the model gets progressively slower.

Comment: LeirsW you are completely right! Now that I did this change its alot faster. I can sacrifices that small increase in accuracy for the huge improvement in performance.